# Convert jQuery Deferred into Promise/A+ compliant code with unknown executor function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I am using jQuery Deferred for some asynchronous event handling. More or less
due to theoretical purity of my code I want to be Promise/A+ compliant. (The
more practical reason is that later I can update my code to use native Promise
implementations as soon as all major browsers support them.)

However, I use a particular feature of jQuery's Deferred that sets it apart
from Promise/A+ and I do not know how to work around it. Hence, I would
like to know how I can solve the following problem in a Promise/A+ compliant
manner.

The core of the problem is that I already need the Promise object in order
to bind a handler to it before I know the exact executor of the promise,
because the executor depends on some parameters that will become known later.
With jQuery's Deferred this is not a problem because I can create an "empty"
Deferred first, bind some handler to it and then attach the executor to it.
With Promise/A+ the executator must be immediately given as the parameter
of the constructor and will be immediately executed even before the
constructor of the Promise returns.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
// Create "empty" deferred
deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

// Attach one or more handlers
deferred.then(
  function onFullfilled( value ) {
    // do something
  }
);

// Somewhere at some totally different part of code after the particular
// URL has become known

jQuery.ajax( "www.myhost.com/my/url", {
  error: function( jqXHR ) {
    deferred.reject( jqXHR );
  },
  success: function( data, status, jqXHR ) {
    deferred.resolve( jqXHR );
  }
});
```

With Promise/A+ I have to do something like this but I can't:

```
// Create promise
promise = new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
  // Error, ups: I do not know the URL yet
  jQuery.ajax( "www.myhost.com/my/url", {
    error: function( jqXHR ) {
      resolve( jqXHR );
    },
    success: function( data, status, jqXHR ) {
      reject( jqXHR );
    }
  });
);

// Attach one or more handlers
promise.then(
  function onFullfilled( value ) {
    // do something
  }
);
```

Thanks you!

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec

https://www.promisejs.org/

https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: If you just want to simulate a Deferred using ES6 standard promises, you can do that in a few lines of code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651780/why-does-the-promise-constructor-need-an-executor/37673534#37673534

Comment: Basically, what you really should do is `getUrlLater().then($.ajax).then(onFulfilled)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can always keep the resolver around instead of using a deferred for the same purpose: `var resolver; new Promise(function(r) { resolver = r }).then(onFulfilled); /* later */ resolver($.ajax(…))`

Comment: Just saying, Promises/A+ does not forbid the usage of deferreds to create promises. All it does specify is the behaviour of the `then` method (which jQuery fails)