# Can an ES6 JavaScript promise be resolved by anything else if it is not resolved by the executor?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

If a promise is created this way:

```
myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {});
```

Can this promise be ever resolved by any way?  Obviously, the executor is not resolving it in this case, so can the promise be ever resolved?

I think if it is jQuery, it can be resolved by `deferred.resolve()` so that the related promise `deferred.promise()` is resolved.

Comment: If you monkeypatched `window.Promise`, yes, but pretty sure that's not what you're thinking about

Comment: @CertainPerformance you mean you actually change the mechanics of `Promise`? For example, when the promise is created, assign the `resolve` to `promise.resolve` so that the promise can resolve itself by `promise.resolve()`?

Comment: Or just call `.resolve()` yourself in the constructor, if you really want to muck things up. You're not really changing the mechanics of how Promises work, you're corrupting `window.Promise` to do something non-spec-compliant

Comment: See also [Why does the Promise constructor need an executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37651780/1048572) - ES6 promises don't use the deferred pattern.

Answer (score 3):

No, the promise can only be resolved or rejected by the `resolve` and `reject` functions, respectively.

If these functions aren't called nor exposed, the promise will remain in pending state forever.

That's also a security level, as it helps you ensure the promise you wait for will resolve to the value you expect and when you expect; and allows you to safely return an internal promise, as it is (without any hazards or leaking secrets).

To make a promise, that relies on another promise you don't have control over, but can be resolved (or rejected) manually, regardless of the original, you can use the `Promise.race()` function:

```js
//The original promise that may pend forever
const original = new Promise(()=>{})

//Controller promise, whose resolver is exposed (or contains the logic needed for "manual" resolution)
let resolve
const controller = new Promise(rs=>{resolve=rs})

//The promise you wait for (and can be resolved or rejected either by `original` or `controller`)
const mixed = Promise.race([original,controller])

mixed.then(console.log)

setTimeout(()=>resolve('Resolved'), 2000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign the resolve function to a variable outside the scope of the promise

Comment: This Promise constructor isn't doing that, though. *If a promise is created this way:*

Comment: But their is nothing to stop you doing it manually inside your promise function